# Símbolos raros (en vez de tildes y Ñ) usando include() para referenciar a otro PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8

Tengo 2 archivos :
Este es el primero cuando ejecuto la funcion verdatos(), me sale todo normal es decir con las tildes y las ñ ,en mi bd todas las tablas tienen cojetamiento utf8_general_ci

```
<?php
function verdatos(){
    $host_db = "localhost";
    $user_db = "root";
    $pass_db = "";
    $db_name = "basedatosmaster";
    $tbl_name = "Preguntastable";

    $conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

    if ($conexion->connect_error) {
    die("La conexion falló: " . $conexion->connect_error);
    }


    $query = "SELECT * FROM Preguntastable";

    $result = $conexion->query($query);


    while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "$fila[ID_pregunta] ";
        echo "<h2>$fila[title_preg]</h2> ";
        echo "$fila[sec_pregunta]<br>";
    }
      mysqli_close($conexion);
}
$jeje=verdatos();
?>
```

En cambio cuando lo llamo a otro archivo php me sale simbolos raros en ves de la ñ y las tildes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Preguntas</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Preguntas:</legend>
        <div>
            <?php
                include("verpregu.php");
                $jeje=verdatos();
            ?>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podría ser que tengas la base de datos configurada en otro tipo de codificación
en mysql vas a operaciones y cambias el cotejamiento o algo así

Comment: ademas de <meta charset="utf-8" />, abre el archivo en el block de notas y coloca la codificacion en utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que `PHP`, por defecto, siempre devuelve el siguiente encabezado: `"Content-Type: text/html"`  por lo tanto debe añadir el charset. Intente las siguientes opciones. Añadir.

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <!-- O - - >
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
     /*  O */
   <?php header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); ?>
   /* O */
   <?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=
      ISO-8859-1') ; ?>
```

Comment: Probe y al final este lo soluciono 
`<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');` 
Lo añadí en el primer archivo , gracias .

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza en el head de HTML:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Y en PHP después de establecer la conexión a la base de datos, así:

```
$conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

    if ($conexion->connect_error) {
    die("La conexion falló: " . $conexion->connect_error);
    }

$conexion->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```